# Rodrigues function in openCV keeps giving error 'ValueError: matrix must be 2-dimensional' even with 2d arrays

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

So I have this code

```
#rotation matrix
R_mtx, jac = cv2.Rodrigues(rvecs[0])

cameraPosition = -R_mtx.T * np.matrix(tvecs)

cameraPosition
```

and the array rvecs from the callibrate camera function which is:

```
[array([[ 1.8774334 ],
       [-0.02710091],
       [ 0.25779132]])] 

arr=rvecs[0]
print (arr.ndim)
```

This code gives out 2

So therefore the code is supposed to work because I am fulfilling the requirements for the function to work. But for some reason it doesn't. I tried looking into the code for the error and there is nothing wrong there too.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected the error but it was also showing on the second line. I just corrected it too with
cameraPosition = -R_mtx.T * np.matrix(tvecs[0])